# Copying and Pasting a Vertical Line in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste

I've inserted a vertical line onto a page and I'd like to copy and paste it to all the other pages; however, when I try to do so, it keeps indenting over incrementally each time (see example below). Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

What it does:

```
|
  |
    |
      |
```

What I want:

```
|

|

|

|
```

Comment: Why not use a line shape instead?

Comment: I am using a line shape. I'm just using the vertical bar as an example.

Comment: can you add an image of what the line looks like?

Answer (score 1):

From with in Word 2007,

1. Click the **Office button** (upper left corner on the screen)
2. Choose **Word** options
3. Choose **Proofing**
4. Choose **Auto Correct** options
5. Choose **Auto Format as you type**
6. Under **Apply as you type** *uncheck* Automatic numbered lists

Note that these numbers will not automatically increment, they will be plain text numbers.

When you want just re enable it. I hope it would help you..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can use bar tabs to make the lines.

Comment: can you elaborate on what a "bar tab" is